# bootstrap JavaScript issues in mobile

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

My bootstrap JavaScript components(like collapse, tab) are not working in mobile devices, but the drop down is working correctly.

Comment: You might have voilated the structure  of bootstrap collapse and tab. Try to start with basic and check if basic works.

Answer (score 0):

When you use Bootstrap , it's better if use basic template: [Basic Template](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#template)

But your problem , this line in your html code is missing .

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```